# Samsung galaxy S2 Storage management

Tags: storage, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I used to have an HTC Desire: there was an internal memory and my micro-SD card. I could navigate easily via file explorer to each.

With S II, I have also a micro-SD inserted however I can only navigate to the so-called USB storage section of the phone.

I am confused, how is storage managed in the S2 and how I can eplore the content of my micro-SD card?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9509/whats-the-difference-between-sd-card-and-usb-storage

Answer (score 1):

In the Galaxy S your phone storage is the same as any other phone's storage, but there is separate "internal SD" mounted at `/sdcard/` that is treated by apps as if it were the external SD card.  The actual external card is mounted at `/sdcard/external_sd/`.

(Actually, I'm not sure if `/sdcard/` is an alias, since you can also see it at `/mnt/sdcard/`.  There is no entry for the external SD in `/mnt/`, but you can of course access it via `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/` as well.)