# Samsung Galaxy S2 not enough storage

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Galaxy S2 and a memory card installed. There are tons of free space on both. When I install any app, it downloads and then says `not enough storage`. How to solve this problem?

It's running ICS, and it's the latest available for it in my region.

I tried moving most apps to the SD card and uninstalled some. I also restarted the phone as well. Now, it shows low on space notification in the notification bar.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. Please check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for a starter, as it contains some first-aid. If you were able to solve your issue by this, please answer your own question and describe how. Otherwise, please [edit] your question with what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks!

Comment: @k1chy I don't think this question is the same. The question you linked is about the storage filling up for no apparent reason. This one is about installing apps when the storage appears to have lots of space.

Comment: @Dan, it appears so. I will remove the comment.

Answer (score 2):

There was a [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58168/why-am-i-constantly-running-out-of-space-on-my-galaxy-s2/64061) similar to yours a while back. It refered to a [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818049/insufficient-storage-available-even-there-is-lot-of-free-space-in-device-memor) with a overwhelmingly positive answer.

One of the answers is to clear `dumpstack`. Here is the excerpt from the Stackoverflow answer.

> Here's a very simple solution that works on my Samsung Galaxy S II and NOTE 1 ; I have no idea about other models:
>
> ```
> Open the Phone app and switch to Keypad.
> Dial *#9900#
> On the screen that appears, click on the button labelled "Delete dumpstate/logcat".
> ```
>
> I've restored about one GB of system space this way.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried it and I Still get insufficient space error. And when i did that nothing happened to system storage. When I go to the storage settings, there is system storage and usb storage. System storage has about 0.2 GB free and usb storage had 7 GB out of eleven. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must root, flash etc and then install a new rom. I had all of this crap on my S2 so I just upgraded to a Nexus 5. Best thing I ever did

Answer (score -1):

Root and flash your phone it solves anything (not only in my experience)

Comment: Well I am looking for a solution without rooting. I will do it if nothing else works but for now I don't want to root it.