# Delete dumpstate/logcat without dialer

Tags: insufficient-memory, tablet, delete

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 P5110 wihtout SIM nor dialer app.

It's gone out of memory so I'm trying to delete the log files which I suspect can be occupying about 1 GB.

The issue is that I can't use the [*#9900#](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58168/why-am-i-constantly-running-out-of-space-on-my-galaxy-s2/67513#67513) method because of the lack of dialer.

My tablet is not rooted. Is there other way to delete the system logs? I can't achieve to find any.

Comment: I didn't know there was a dialer function to delete logs but I suspect you can download a dialer app from the store right? Or use a file explorer and search for files containing "log". I used ES explorer(with root access) for this.

Comment: File explorers don't work because my tablet is not rooted (the system logs are in protected space). I just tried a dialer app and it doesn't recognize the code *#9900#

Comment: Do you know the activity name which gets launched when that code is dialed? If yes, then launch that activity directly using [tag:ADB].

Comment: I don't know it and can't find on the web.